# Rotate an object with 'Quaternion.Slerp' in world space

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics, rotation, quaternion

I'm currently working on a multiplayer skydiving Unity game in which i rotate the players like this:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, desiredRotation, delta);
```

Now this rotates the player relative to it's own rotation. I know rotation in world space is done by multiplying the quaternion of the desired positon with the quaternion of the current position like this:

```
localRotation = transform.rotation * desiredRotation
worldRotation = desiredRotation * transform.rotation
```

But how do i slerp to that position in world space?

*Thank you all in advance and have a great day!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you grab the total rotation quaternion.

```
fullRelativeRotation = Quaternion.inverse(transform.rotation)*desiredRotation;
rotationTime = 0;
//persist over frames
```

then every frame until you complete the rotation you slerp the identity quaternion with it.

```
if(rotationTime < 1){
    rotationThisFrame = Quaternion.Slerp(Quaternion.identity, fullRelativeRotation, min(delta, 1-rotationTime));
    rotationTime+=delta;
    transform.rotation = transform.rotation * rotationThisFrame;
}
```

Comment: Some remarks.

1: You can store the `rotationThisFrame` outside the if clause. It does not depend on anything that changes with time.

2: If, on the other hand, you'd used the `rotationTime` and stored the initial and final rotations, then recomputing the quat on the slerp path every frame would have been justified. But, in that case, you would have simply set `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(..)`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, in order to get from a local coordinate frame to world coordinates, you need to go through the rotation hierarchy, like `worldToParent.rotation * parentToLocal.rotation = worldToLocal.rotation`.

So, in order to rotate towards a desired orientation in world space, your computation look something like `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(worldToLocal.rotation, desiredRotation, delta)`. Note that `desiredRotation` in this case is not transformed, as it is a relative rotation anyways and will thus be applied within the same coordinate frame as the base rotation (in this case `worldToLocal`, defined as above, which resides in the world frame).

Comment: Maybe, to be safer/clearer, mention that the user must not tamper with the `worldToLocal` and `desiredRotation` amounts during the rotation sequence of frames. They are set prior to starting the rotation itself.

Comment: Also many thanks to you! Your solution also worked.